# Simplify this boolean expression

Tags: propositional-calculus, boolean-algebra

$$ \neg P\lor(P \land Q) $$

I want the above expression to be equivalent to

$$\neg P \lor Q$$

But I don't understand how to prove this. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Have you considered trying truth tables?

Comment: Use [Distributivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributive_property#Propositional_logic).

Comment: I think it should be achieved by using algebra of propositions laws

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the distributive law,

¬P∨(P∧Q) = (¬P∨P)∧(¬P∨Q)

But ¬P∨P is **always** true, so the above

= ¬P∨Q